# SASS SCSS increment number on data-attribute

Tags: css, loops, sass

I have a for loop in sass

```
@for $i from 1 through 7 {
    .m0#{$i}{
        a[aria-current="page"]{
        background-color: nth($m_col_lvl_04, $i);
        }
        a[data-submenu-id="submenu-id_p#{$i}"]{
            background-color: nth($m_col_lvl_04, $i);
        }
    }
}
```

aria-current="page" part works and adds the correct colours.

The second part does not because I can't work out how to add the increment to the data-attribute.
[data-submenu-id="submenu-id_p0X"] where X = 1-7

I have used this to increment a number to an image so there must be a way. It just eludes me :-)

Any help is very welcome.

```
background: url("../img/icons/m0#{$i}-icon-important.png") no-repeat;
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it's worked

Comment: In your code you have written `submenu-id_p#{$i}` but in your question `submenu-id_p0X`. I'm guessing the issue is that you are missing the `0` from the id?

Comment: @SamWillis I believe you are right the 0 is missing. How did I miss that . Thanks.